# How to control qx.data.Array via qx.ui.table.Table

Tags: qooxdoo

I have qx.data.Array variable consits of objects. How to connect Array to table ?
I supose I need kind of mapping in code below. The rows in table are empty but count of them is correct.

```
var rowData = theStore.getModel();  //it is qx.data.Array type
var tableModel = new qx.ui.table.model.Simple();
tableModel.setData(rowData);
var table = new qx.ui.table.Table(tableModel);
```

Thanks,
 Karol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your data model:

[image: map array]

you have an array of objects/map.
In this case you can use 
`tableModel.setDataAsMapArray(rowData)`
http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.table.model.Simple~setDataAsMapArray 
 instead of `tableModel.setData(rowData)`.

However, you have to set the column ids of the model first so qooxdoo can establish the mapping from the data to the columns. 
e.g.
`tableModel.setColumns(Object.keys(rowData[0]))` should work

Comment: Thank you adrelino. It solved problem, additionaly I had to add toArray() function (var rowData = theStore.getModel().toArray();). When I edit row and modify it the change is not reflected in theStore.getModel(). Is the way to have source rows (theStore.getModel()) in table not copy of them ?

Comment: there is not data binding between theStore <--> tableModel , so you have to do that manually.


1. do you edit the row using qooxdoo's table + tableModel?
2. or do you edit the source data in theStore?


<-
if you call tableModel.getDataAsMapArray() you should get the modified data from the qooxdoo table.


->
And in the second case, just call setData(rowData) again to overwrite the old data

Answer (score 1):

qx.ui.table.Table doesn't handle binding natively thus you cannot bind your model (the store) to the table and have changes made inside the table reflected into the store without manually synchronizing.

Creating your own tableModel (implementing the qx.ui.table.ITableModel interface) is quite easy, you can create a custom table model, then you can bind your store to the model of your custom model having bidirectionnal binding between table cells and store model.